# Check for a deafened user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

In discord.js, how can I check that a user inside a voice channel is deafened? I read the docs and I couldn't find anything related to this

Comment: Your question is quite unclear on how you explain `deafened` but in case you want to check if the client has permission to send audio to the voice channel, you can refer to https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=speakable

Comment: thank you but it has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look under `GuildMember` there is a `.deaf` property as well as `.selfDeaf` and `.serverDeaf`. This will return a boolean value.

Resource: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=deaf

So for example:

```
message.member.deaf
message.member.selfDeaf
message.member.serverDeaf
```